# Generate Insert Scripts with IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a master table in a database.

Example Menu table

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| Id        | Key       | Display Text| ParentId| CreatedOn
+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------------------+
| 1         | Home      | Home        | NULL    |2014-01-14 21:17:37.387 |
| 2         | About     | About Us    | NULL    |2014-01-14 21:17:37.387 |
| 3         | Contact   | Contact Us  | NULL    |2014-01-14 21:17:37.387 |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+---------+------------------------+
```

I used to generate master data script like below for each record.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Menu] WHERE Id=1 AND Key='Home')
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu]
           (Id
           ,[Key]
           ,[DisplayText]
           ,[ParentId]
           ,[CreatedOn])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'Home'
           ,'Home'
           ,NULL
           ,GETDATE()
           )
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF

END
GO
```

-- Repeating same manual record creation work for all 70 records & other master data(`10k rows`)

However there is some existing table `ApplicationMenu` in another database is having same column, datatypes. We would like to generate the below script automatically for us by using some stored procedure.

Is it possible to create a procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGenerateInsertScripts
(
  @SourceTableName VARCHAR(100),
  @ExistsWhereClauseTemplate NVARCHAR(1000),
  @TargetTableName VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

 -- In some loop create those above insert statements
END
```

We would like to execute like below

```
  exec spGenerateInsertScripts 'ApplicationMenu'
                               , 'WHERE Id={Id} AND Key={Key}'
                               , 'Menu'
```

Here the **{Id} & {Key}** will be read from every row from existing table and replaced.

This will actually reduce lot of manual work for us.

***Note:***

We could not use SQL server insert script generation tool, since we want to check the data existence as well as need to keep the records added by user using our application.

Need to generate a insert scripts so that we can just run in future, even when ApplicationTable is not available

Is it possible to write such a procedure to generate insert script from other table based on existence? Like how sql server `Generate Scripts work for table creation by looking into INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table, same way I am expecting for this.

Final output of the procedure would be like `PRINT @insert_Sql_Statements`

Comment: So you want to use the ApplicationMenu table (in other database) to create rows in the Menu database (if those rows do not already exist). Using the Id and Key columns from ApplicationMenu?

Comment: why dont you just create a stored procedure which accepts table valued parameter and pass the values to the stored procedure , and return the values that was added to the target table. ????

Comment: @Umair, Yes. Both the tables are having same column name, datatypes. I would like to import all ApplicationMenu to my Menu table only if they not exists

Comment: @M.Ali, I need a insert script, so that I can run anytime later, even when ApplicationMenu table is not available..

Answer (score 5):

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id INT, [Key] VARCHAR(30),[Display Text] VARCHAR(30), ParentId INT,  CreatedOn DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
(1,'Home'   ,'Home'      ,NULL, '2014-01-14 21:17:37.387'), 
(2,'About'  ,'About Us'  ,NULL, '2014-01-14 21:17:37.387'),
(3,'Contact','Contact Us',NULL, '2014-01-14 21:17:37.387')
```

**Query to Create Script**

```
SELECT  N'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Menu] WHERE Id='+  CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
       + ' AND Key='''+ CAST([Key] AS NVARCHAR(1000)) +''')' + CHAR(10) 
        + N'BEGIN ' + CHAR(10) + '
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON ' + CHAR(10) + ' 

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu]      ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   (Id    ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,[Key] ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,[DisplayText]' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,[ParentId]' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,[CreatedOn])' + CHAR(10) + ' 
             VALUES' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ( '  + ISNULL(CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(10)), 'NULL') + ' ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,''' + ISNULL(CAST([Key] AS NVARCHAR(1000)), 'NULL') +''' ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,''' + ISNULL(CAST([Display Text] AS NVARCHAR(1000)), 'NULL')  + ''' ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,' +  ISNULL(CAST(ParentId AS NVARCHAR(10)), 'NULL')  + ' ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ,GETDATE() ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
                   ) ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
        END ' + CHAR(10) + ' 
        GO ' + CHAR(10) + ' '+ CHAR(10)
FROM @Table
```

**Generated Script**

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                                                                                                                                                                                                          (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Menu] WHERE Id=1 AND Key='Home') BEGIN      SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON         INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu]                 (Id               ,[Key]            ,[DisplayText]           ,[ParentId]           ,[CreatedOn])        VALUES           ( 1            ,'Home'            ,'Home'            ,NULL            ,GETDATE()            )       SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF       END       GO                 ║
║ IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Menu] WHERE Id=2 AND Key='About') BEGIN      SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON         INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu]                 (Id               ,[Key]            ,[DisplayText]           ,[ParentId]           ,[CreatedOn])        VALUES           ( 2            ,'About'            ,'About Us'            ,NULL            ,GETDATE()            )       SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF       END       GO           ║
║ IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Menu] WHERE Id=3 AND Key='Contact') BEGIN      SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON         INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu]                 (Id               ,[Key]            ,[DisplayText]           ,[ParentId]           ,[CreatedOn])        VALUES           ( 3            ,'Contact'            ,'Contact Us'            ,NULL            ,GETDATE()            )       SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF       END       GO     ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Note**

I have got results back in `Grid` but you can export the results to a file or to text and copy paste it into your query window when you want to execute it.

Comment: Awwww, 24 minutes slower for basically the same answer. +1 to you sir, for getting there first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, what you're proposing (where clause as a parameter) doesn't sound too good and can cause a WHOLE lot of other issues (e.g. SQL injection, verifying SQL string is in correct format, etc).

How about this approach, which uses linked servers

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Menu] ([Id],[Key],[DisplayText],[ParentId],[CreatedOn])
SELECT a.Id, a.Key, a.Key, NULL, GETDATE()
FROM [ApplicationMenu_Instance].[ApplicationMenu_Database].[dbo].[ApplicationMenu] AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Menu] AS m
    WHERE m.Id = a.Id
        AND m.Key = a.Key
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF
GO
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you want to return the insert script, how about dynamic SQL then:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGenerateInsertScripts
(
    @SourceTable VARCHAR(100),
    @TargetTable VARCHAR(100)
)  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON
    GO

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @TargetTable + '] ([Id],[Key],[DisplayText],[ParentId],[CreatedOn])
    SELECT a.Id, a.Key, a.Key, NULL, GETDATE()
    FROM ' + @SourceTable + '  AS a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[' + @TargetTable + '] AS m
        WHERE m.Id = a.Id
            AND m.Key = a.Key
    )

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF
    GO
   ';

    SELECT @SQL;
END
```

Comment: But i need it as a `TEXT SCRIPT` so that I can run that any time even when applicationmenu is not available. I want to generate the script text when ApplicationMenu is available, after that I want to re-run any time.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Why can't you just create an sp with the code above and then execute it whenever you want to?

Comment: Do you want it so you can decide on the location of the source application menu table (by passing in a parameter)?

Comment: I am looking similar way like generating stored procedure script with the help of sql server Generate Scripts tool. In that you can select create a table, when table is not exists in the database. So automatically it will generate a table script for us by checking with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table. Same way

Comment: I want the value statement instead of `SELECT a.Id, a.Key, a.Key, NULL, GETDATE() FROM ApplicationMenu`. Please check my question. As of now I am inserting one by one. I want some helper procedure to produce those records by reading another table..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45229/discussion-between-umair-and-billa)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SQL statement to generate the required insert statements. You can then just copy and paste the output into wherever you want to execute the query.

Its not a generic solution to creating a script that generates insert statements into one table from another table, but it will dramatically reduce the manual work required for your specific case. You can configure the name of the target table, but the column names and values and the name of the table the data is being retrieved from are hardcoded.

It assumes that the target table entered has the same schema as the table the data is being retrieved from.

```
DECLARE @TARGET_TABLE AS VARCHAR(100) = '[dbo].[Menu]'

SELECT Script
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, [Key], 0 AS [Order], 
        'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TARGET_TABLE + 
        ' WHERE Id=' + CONVERT(varchar(100), Id) + 
        ' AND Key=''' + [Key] + ''')' AS Script
    FROM ApplicationMenu
    UNION
    SELECT Id, [Key], 1 AS [Order], 'BEGIN' AS Script
    FROM ApplicationMenu
    UNION
    SELECT Id, [Key], 2, 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TARGET_TABLE + ' ON'
    FROM ApplicationMenu
    UNION
    SELECT Id, [Key], 3, 
        'INSERT INTO ' + @TARGET_TABLE + 
        ' VALUES(' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(11), Id) + ', ''' + 
        [Key] + ''', ''' + 
        [DisplayText] + ''', ' + 
        ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(11), ParentId), 'NULL') + 
        ', GETDATE())'
    FROM ApplicationMenu
    UNION
    SELECT Id, [Key], 4, 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TARGET_TABLE + ' OFF'
    FROM ApplicationMenu
    UNION
    SELECT Id, [Key], 5, 'END'
    FROM ApplicationMenu
) AS ScriptInfo
ORDER BY Id, [Key], [Order]
```

Honestly, the script is a bit painful to look at, but it gets the job done.

If you truly want a generic solution to the problem, you'll probably have more luck implementing it in some sort of programming language (like C#). The upside of implementing it in C# is that you can then import the library into SQL server and call it like a stored procedure (I think, I've never done that sort of thing before).

Additionally there are tools available that will do generate this sort of script for you. If I remember correctly, RedGate SQL Data Compare will do this sort of thing fairly easily. There are probably others.